# Which windows form control is best for presenting data in a tabular fashion?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, windows-forms-designer

I need to present the output on the form in rows and columns. Is there a control to make that task easier? I am using visual studio 2010 and coding in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for DataGridView.
Which looks like so (don't worry, the colors are fully configurable (;):

[image]

And has many advances capabilities such as DataBinding and paging.
Here's a [tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/raj1979/datagridview09052008041419am/datagridview.aspx) to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Though you asked about WinForms, if you use WPF, in WFP 4.0 (.NET 4) there's a [DataGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) that you can use. It's quite flexible.